# In Terraria for PlayStation 4 how do you get souls of sight?

Tags: terraria-console

So I play Terraria, ALOT. I *really* want a Dao Of Pow. How do I obtain souls of sight? Is it easy?

Answer (score 0):

In all versions of Terraria, [Souls of Sight](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Soul_of_Sight) are dropped by the early hardmode boss [The Twins](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Twins). The Twins are considered one of the harder mechanical bosses, and you'll likely want to face them while equipped with Adamantite/Titanium equipment and items crafted after defeating [The Destroyer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Destroyer).

However, the [Dao of Pow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dao_of_Pow) does *not* use Souls of Sight in its crafting recipe. Rather, it uses [Souls of Light](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Soul_of_Light) and [Souls of Night](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Soul_of_Night). These two soul types are dropped randomly by any enemies in the [Underground Hallow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Hallow) and the [Underground Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Corruption)/[Crimson](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Crimson) respectively.